# the most-positive-fixnum in emacs

Tags: types, emacs, numbers, lisp

Upon checking the variable in 'most-positive-fixnum' in emacs, it output:

```
most-positive-fixnum is a variable defined in ‘data.c’.
Its value is 2305843009213693951
Documentation:
The largest value that is representable in a Lisp integer.
```

It's log2 value:

```
In [8]: math.log2(2305843009213693951)
Out[8]: 61.0
```

why set is as `2 **61` rather than `2**62`,  or `2**63`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because there are tag bits: when encountering an object a dynamically-typed language needs to know what type it is.  To do this there must be some 'tag' information which tells it that.  A naive approach would be to represent all objects by at least two machine words: a word of tag information and at least one word for the object itself.  This is a disaster for objects like integers, as it means you need two machine words for even small integers which you would expect to fit in one.  This in turn means that, for instance, `(+ 1 2)` needs to allocate storage, which you would like it not to do.

To get around this you reduce the maximum size of small integers (fixums) and use some of the spare bits in the word as the tag that says 'this is a fixnum'.  There is a very clever trick you can do here called 'low tags': if you reserve, for instance, two tag bits at the low end of the word you can make them be (going in little-endian order of bit):

- 0 0: even fixnum
- 0 1: odd fixnum;
- 1 0, 1 1: two other kinds of object

And the clever thing is that this means your fixnums can be one bit bigger than you would expect, because the low-order bit of an even fixnum is 0: it overlaps with the tag bits.  Addition with fixnums represented like this can use machine operations (modulo overflow), while multiplication requires a shift, which is typically essentially free since it does not touch memory.  I don't know if elisp uses low-tags although I kind of assume it does.